# Why doesn’t this alignment work?

Tags: align

I try to use this to make the equivalent signs align

```
\begin{align*}
$32\cdot2+m &= 3\cdot2^3-2\cdot2+3$\\
$ &= 3\cdot8-4+3$
\end{align*}
```

I have the amsmath package and have read the forum here on how to align text but anything I try to do doesn’t work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `align`-environment is a maths environment. So you don't need to use `$`'s inside it. Also the third `\` and the blank lines need to be removed. So you get this

```
\begin{align*}
  32 \cdot 2 + m &= 3 \cdot 2^3 - 2 \cdot 2 + 3 \\
                 &= 3 \cdot 8 - 4 + 3
\end{align*}
```

If you really want a blank line (maybe you find it reads better), you can comment that line like so:

```
\begin{align*}
%
  32 \cdot 2 + m &= 3 \cdot 2^3 - 2 \cdot 2 + 3 \\
%
                 &= 3 \cdot 8 - 4 + 3
%
\end{align*}
```

The `%`-signs at the beginning of the line means that it is non-existent as far as LaTeX's concerned.